# How to select a sql string parameter as an original value with multi lines

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a query like below. When i use select @sql, it flattens the string to 1 row. How to select the original string value as it is?

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)= 
'SELECT 
A,
B,
C
FROM X'

SELECT @SQL
```

Result is:

```
SELECT   A,  B,  C  FROM X
```

What i need:

```
SELECT 
A,
B,
C
FROM X
```

Comment: The result only looks that way because you're using Management Studio. You *are* getting back the result with newlines. If you toggle "result to text" (Ctrl+T) you'll get the value as-is. Of course, if you actually *want* to split that value into multiple different rows, that's another matter (use `STRING_SPLIT` or one of the many related questions on how to split strings on earlier versions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `print` command :

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)= 
'SELECT 
A,
B,
C
FROM X'

print @sql
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable does contain the CRLFs. The client (I guess SSMS?) removes them.

I don't know if there is an option for SSMS to show the CRLFs in the result grid. But to retain them on copying or saving the result you can check "Tool" -> "Options..." -> "Query Results" -> "SQL Server" -> "Results to Grid" -> "Retain CR/LF on copy or save".

For any other client look in its documentation.